# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token c JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm getting an `uncaught Syntax Error` when I try to parse a `JSON string`, I'm not sure why it is failing. I've tested the JSON string and it is valid.

Can someone please help me with this issue.

My code snippet (in chrome) is as follows:

```
var input = 'c:out escapeXml="false" value="[{"registeredCustomers":"81","node":"RAGS"},{"registeredCustomers":"39","node":"SBSA"}]" />';
var arr1 = [];
obj1 = JSON.parse(input);
```

Comment: It doesn't look like valid JSON to me. The only valid JSON is the part after `value=`.

Comment: But isn't JSTL only supposed to return the value, which would then be what comes after the value attribute?

Comment: What is JSTL? You don't seem to be using anything special, you're just parsing the string.

Comment: Sounds like you should parse the element as xml and get parse the value attribute with JSON. Otherwise you'd have to use some kind of regex but that will be harder than creating an xml document.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do

```
input = input.replace("c:out escapeXml='false' value='", "")
```

and then `JSON.parse(input);`

Comment: Also get rid of the ` /> ` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

`Json.parse` expect the string. You can try this:

```
   var input = '[{\"registeredCustomers":"81","node":"RAGS"},      
   "registeredCustomers":"39","node":"SBSA"\}]';
   var arr1 = [];
   obj1 = JSON.parse(input);
   console.log(obj1);
```

it will return the following output:

```
[Object, Object, $family: function, $constructor: function, each: function, clone: function, clean: function…]
0: Object
node: "RAGS"
registeredCustomers: "81"
__proto__: Object
1: Object
node: "SBSA"
registeredCustomers: "39"
__proto__: Object
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error **Unexpected token c JSON.parse** due to the multiple time usage of quote in the input. And the error message is pointing to starting of the line.

```
value="[{"registeredCustomers":"81","node":"RAGS"},{"registeredCustomers":"39","node":"SBSA"}]"
```